What is the difference between naturalized and derived citizenship of the US?
I'm trying to understand the difference between naturalized and derived citizenship in the US. I've been doing some research, but I'm still a bit confused about the distinctions and the implications of each.
Could someone please explain:

The main differences between naturalized and derived citizenship? This could include things like eligibility requirements, the application process, and rights and responsibilities.
Are there any potential drawbacks to derived citizenship?

I'd really appreciate any insights or information you can provide.
Thanks!

What Is a Naturalized or Derived Citizen?
There are 4 ways in which someone can obtain citizenship:

The first is to be born in the United States or in one of the territories.
The second is to be born to parents who are citizens, something referred to as “acquisition” of citizenship.
The third is called naturalization and this means you obtain citizenship after you submit an application and proper documentation, and pass an examination.
The fourth is called derivation, and this means one parent becomes a naturalized citizen and you, by extension, receive derivation citizenship.

What does naturalized or derived citizen mean?
Both terms are ways of identifying people who have received citizenship without being born into a country, but one is earned through a series of requirements, tests, and oaths while the other is effectively given to underage children when their parents complete the series of requirements, tests, and oaths. 
When someone is born, they automatically US citizenship if either of their parents are US citizens. If their parents have other citizenships, it’s complicated - sometimes they automatically have that citizenship, sometimes they are eligible to become citizens, it depends on the relevant nation’s law. The process of derived citizenship replicates this concept for people who become naturalized citizens and have underage children. It is effectively a way for their children to automatically receive the citizenship that they now have just the same as they would have received it when they were born. This process of derived citizenship can also help blended families.

For example, Sun married a military man, John. Sun had 2 children from a previous marriage. Sun moved to the United States as a permanent resident with her new husband John. After two years she was able to apply for naturalized citizenship and become an official U.S. citizen. The child she and John had one year ago is automatically a U.S. citizen because John is a US citizen. The two children she had from a previous marriage can receive derived citizenship now that Sun and John are citizens.

So, the main differences between naturalized and derived citizenship are the following:

Eligibility:

Naturalized: Requires being a lawful permanent resident (green card holder) for a certain period, meeting residency requirements, demonstrating good moral character, passing English and civics tests, and taking an oath of allegiance.
Derived: Automatic for children under 18 when their parents become naturalized citizens, provided they have lawful permanent resident status and live with the citizen parent(s).


Process:

Naturalized: Involves a formal application, background checks, interviews, and tests.
Derived: Generally simpler, often requiring only filing Form N-600 and providing supporting documents.


Rights and Responsibilities: Both naturalized and derived citizens enjoy the same rights and responsibilities, including voting, holding a US passport, and accessing government benefits.

Speaking about potential drawbacks of derived citizenship there may be several such as:

Limited control: Children have no say in the process and may not understand the implications of becoming a US citizen.
Loss of original citizenship: Depending on the child's country of origin and its laws, they might lose their original citizenship upon acquiring US citizenship through derivation.
Tax implications: US citizens are subject to US taxes on their worldwide income, even if they live abroad. This can create complex tax situations for individuals with derived citizenship who may have ties to other countries.

Mainly used this source: https://lawrina.org/guides/personal/immigration-law/naturalized-or-derived-citizen/

"If their parents have multiple citizenships, they are a dual citizen, children receive both of those." Some countries like China don't recognise dual citizenships.

Can’t naturalization be revoked ? That’s a huge difference.

If naturalization is revoked, do the children lose their derived citizenship?

Is derived citizenship transitive? If a teenage child has a baby, and their parent is naturalized, do both the child and grandchild become derived citizens?

FWIW, for quirky historical reasons, people born in the U.S. territory of American Samoa are not citizens at birth. https://www.yewlegal.com/how-can-an-american-samoan-qualify-for-u-s-citizenship/

Also, to be clear: derived citizenship is one kind of naturalization, it is a subset of the category of naturalized citizens. All citizens have the same citizenship rights with the sole exception of eligibility to serve as President or Vice President which is restricted to "natural born citizens" a category limited to the first two types of citizenship acquisition at the start of this answer.

And naturalization  can be revoked. A very big difference.

@GeorgeWhite The grounds for revocation of naturalization are extremely narrow and are limited to circumstances in the application for naturalization itself only. Historically, denaturalization was pursued by the U.S. government in very small numbers, averaging only eleven cases per year between 1990 and 2017. https://www.ilrc.org/sites/default/files/resources/denaturalization_pa.pdf Ths is about 0.002% of all naturalizations. https://www.uscis.gov/citizenship-resource-center/naturalization-statistics

Ok, a very big difference to a few people.

The president limitation actually affects way fewer people in practice.
